# Can I change the display name of column in a listview using JSlink

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, list-view, xslt, jslink

I've a requirement to change the display name of a column in only one view, I've to show 'Responsible' instead of 'Responsible Person'. Is this possible by JSlink ?

Comment: With JSLink you would have to generate the whole header row yourself in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function () {
     var ctxForm = {};
      ctxForm.Templates = {};
      ctxForm.OnPreRender = preTaskFormRenderer;
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);

 function preTaskFormRenderer(overrideCtx) {
       modifyHeaderData(overrideCtx);       
    }


    function modifyHeaderData(overrideCtx)
    {


      var linkTitleField = overrideCtx.ListSchema.Field[1];

      linkTitleField.DisplayName =  linkTitleField.DisplayName+" :changed";
    }


})();
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a lot of work when you can just go into SP Designer and edit the view and change the column name. Very simple to do...