# How to remove the list titles in a webpart

Tags: list, web-part

Can you help me,I want to remove the title headings that have been inserted into a webpart,how can I do that,

I have attached the pic.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way to hide view header would be to use CSS -

1. Add a content editor webpart on view page (under Media & Content Category).
2. Add below code in the content section.

**.ms-viewheadertr { display:none; }**

Answer (score 1):

Shefali has the correct answer but if there are multiple lists on the page this will remove them all. If you want to only target one of them select it in IE Developer of Chrome Developer and find the web part ID. Preface this first. ex `#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ01 .ms-viewheadertr { display:none; }`

I would also put the style tags in... It should look like this 
`<style type="text/css">#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ01 .ms-viewheadertr {display:none;}</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Another way which I do recommend is to use JSLink. The reason is you can reference it within the web part itself.

A similar question was asked here before and I do recommend the answer there:

[Can I change the display name of column in a listview using JSlink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79819/can-i-change-the-display-name-of-column-in-a-listview-using-jslink)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved the simplest way by going to the webpart properties -> appearance -> and choose for "Chrome type == none"

[image]