# How i should edit custom list column name using JS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list

I have a custom list that I need to create a quiz. My issue is that all the columns of all the questions is long, which makes my column too lengthy?

I have actually found results to using JavaScript. 
Reference to the result: [Referencing to this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0ef66ce8-78e9-4610-b25f-a15cad8ce7d2/change-column-title-text-in-listview-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) 
But however, i realised that when I opened a new IE window, the column name is referred back to the original name.

So I would like to know if there's any other possible ways?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Hello, You can check JavaScript and replace code or method that doesn't compatibility with IE. Or you can use JSlink to replace header value. For JSLink this might be help you https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79819/can-i-change-the-display-name-of-column-in-a-listview-using-jslink

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

//alert('b');

$('#diidSort12Priority').text('aaa');

})

</script>
```

Note: you need to change '#diidSort12Priority' to the element id of the column. you can find the element id via IE F12.

If you are using modern view for your list, the code should not work as modern view is not supported for JavaScript code currently, you need to use Classic view.

Comment: Hey yes, this is the script that I've used. but how do i know that I'm on the classic view or the modern view?

Comment: you can check the vedio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb095SsFG_w&feature=youtu.be about them.